# How to add physics package of LaTex in Sphinx

Tags: python, latex, python-sphinx

I want to present a quantum formula in Sphinx.
LaTeX code:

```
\ket{\psi}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\ket{00}+\ket{11})
```

It looks like required the 'physics' package from LaTeX.
How can I add this package in Sphinx?

I tried to modify conf.py of Sphinx with adding two lines. But it doesn't work.

```
# -- Options for LaTeX output -------------------------------------------------
latex_engine = 'xelatex'
latex_elements = {'preamble':r'\usepackage{physics}'}
```

The output of Sphinx:
[image: The output of Sphinx]

Reproduce the issue:

I just did very sample changes on conf.py and index.rst

conf.py:

```py
# Configuration file for the Sphinx documentation builder.
#
# This file only contains a selection of the most common options. For a full
# list see the documentation:
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html

# -- Path setup --------------------------------------------------------------

# If extensions (or modules to document with autodoc) are in another directory,
# add these directories to sys.path here. If the directory is relative to the
# documentation root, use os.path.abspath to make it absolute, like shown here.
#
# import os
# import sys
# sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
import sphinx_rtd_theme


# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------

project = 'aaa'
copyright = 'bbb'
author = 'ccc'

# The full version, including alpha/beta/rc tags
release = '2021'


# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------

# Add any Sphinx extension module names here, as strings. They can be
# extensions coming with Sphinx (named 'sphinx.ext.*') or your custom
# ones.
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.todo']

# Add any paths that contain templates here, relative to this directory.
templates_path = ['_templates']

# List of patterns, relative to source directory, that match files and
# directories to ignore when looking for source files.
# This pattern also affects html_static_path and html_extra_path.
exclude_patterns = []

# -- Options for LaTeX output -------------------------------------------------
latex_engine = 'xelatex'
latex_elements = {'preamble':r'\usepackage{physics}'}

# -- Options for TODO output -------------------------------------------------
todo_include_todos = True

# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------

# The theme to use for HTML and HTML Help pages.  See the documentation for
# a list of builtin themes.
#
html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'


# Add any paths that contain custom static files (such as style sheets) here,
# relative to this directory. They are copied after the builtin static files,
# so a file named "default.css" will overwrite the builtin "default.css".
html_theme_path = [sphinx_rtd_theme.get_html_theme_path()]
```

index.rst:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

Contents
=======================
:math:`\ket{\psi}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\ket{00}+\ket{11})`
```

then, I ran `make html` and got following page:
[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avY3W.png)

Comment: Can you say a little more than just "it doesn't work"? What exactly happens?

Comment: The sphinx cannot compile the LaTeX symbol \ket. I will upload a picture to show what I got from sphinx.

Comment: I uploaded all code I modified. When I ran ```make html```, I didn't get any error in terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

Add the following line in conf.py:

```
mathjax_path = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"
```

This ensures that MathJax 3 is used.

#### More details

If you use math in your RST documents and don't specify a renderer for HTML output in conf.py, MathJax is used.

The default value of [`mathjax_path`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/math.html#confval-mathjax_path) in Sphinx (version 3.4.3) is https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.7/latest.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML (MathJax 2).

With MathJax 2, I got the same bad output as you did. I found the working URL at https://www.mathjax.org/#gettingstarted.

Comment: COOL! Thank you so much.

Comment: MathJax 3 is the default in Sphinx 4.0.0 and later. I think this is a better answer now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75475836/407651.