# How can the mathjax physics package be used in a sphinx documentation?

Tags: python-sphinx, mathjax

The following section in sphinx

```
.. math::

   \vb{R} = \vb{T} \vb{U}^{-1} = \vb{V}^{-1} \vb{T}
```

is rendered as

[image]

What I actually want is this:

[image]

But right now this is only possible if I write

```
.. math::

   \mathbf{R} = \mathbf{T} \mathbf{U}^{-1} = \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{T}
```

or by including the `\require{physics}` tag in the `..math` block, which is not ideal since this is also part of a docstring that is being documented with sphinx autodoc.

I have already tried to adopt the solution from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655706/mathjax-not-rendering-in-sphinx) by adding

```
mathjax_path = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"
```

to my `conf.py` file, but it did not work. How can I properly display desired latex code on my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding

```
mathjax3_config = {
  'loader': {'load': ['[tex]/physics']},
  'tex': {'packages': {'[+]': ['physics']}},
}
```

to the `conf.py` resolves the issue by instructing MathJax to load the `physics` package.